# Python feedparser not using atom/WordPress namespace?

Tags: python, xml, wordpress, feedparser, atom-feed

I'm trying to use [feedparser](http://feedparser.org/) (an excellent library) to parse WordPress export files, and a (minor) inconsistency between WordPress version is causing me a huge headache.

WordPress 2.x doesn't include `atom:link` tags in the XML output ([without_atom_tags.xml](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/780754/atom_issue/without_atom_tags.xml)).  When parsed, namespaced elements are available without the prefix:

```
>>> feed = feedparser.parse("without_atom_tags.xml")
>>> print feed.entries[0].comment_status
u'open'
```

The XML from WordPress 3.x *does* contain `atom:link` tags ([with_atom_tags.xml](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/780754/atom_issue/with_atom_tags.xml)), and you must prefix namespace elements:

```
>>> feed = feedparser.parse("with_atom_tags.xml")
>>> feed.entries[0].wp_comment_status              # <-- Note wp_ prefix
u'open'
>>> feed.entries[0].comment_status
AttributeError: object has no attribute 'comment_status'
```

Interestingly, the prefixes aren't needed if I add `xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"` to the root RSS element ([with_atom_tags_and_namespace.xml](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/780754/atom_issue/with_atom_tags_and_namespace.xml)).

I need to parse all these different formats without modifying the XML.  Is feedparser broken, or am I doing it wrong?  Can I do this without a bunch of nasty conditional code?

Comment: *Update:*  Turns out using the trunk version of feedparser causes all elements to be parsed the same (*with* the wp_ prefix).

Answer (score 0):

Could you add the missing namespaces (atom/wp) to the global list of supported namespaces in feedparser.py directly?

Comment: I downloaded the feedparser.py source in an attempt to try your solution.  Lo and behold, the latest version from trunk corrects this issue!  All attributes are prefixed with the namespace wp_